# Google Earth Engine API: localhost refused to connect

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, docker, github

I'm trying to implement this https://github.com/samsammurphy/gee-atmcorr-S2 in Google Earth Engine using Docker Toolbox for atmospheric correction.

I first install Datalab following the instruction on https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install-datalab-local

Once that's done, it show me the path `guope@DESKTOP-RST8AAG MINGW64 ~/workspace/datalab-ee`

Then I pull the docker image using `docker pull samsammurphy/ee-python3-jupyter-atmcorr:latest`

Then I run `docker run -i -t -p 8888:8888 samsammurphy/ee-python3-jupyter-atmcorr` and it shows me `root@5d7195f4dd85:/#`, which means I'm in a virtual OS.

Then I authenticate my EE account and it shows `Successfully saved authorization token.`

Then I grab the source code `git clone https://github.com/samsammurphy/gee-atmcorr-S2` and navigate to the folder `cd gee-atmcorr-S2/jupyer_notebooks/`.

However, when I copy/paste the URL into my browser, it says `localhost refused to connect.` Ideally, I think it should open the jupyter notebook with the script loaded.

Can anyone please tell me what the problem is and how to fix it?

```
root@88676ad61bbb:/gee-atmcorr-S2/jupyer_notebooks# jupyter-notebook sentinel2_atmospheric_correction.ipynb --ip='*' --port=8888 --allow-root
[W 10:25:15.109 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.
[I 10:25:15.128 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /gee-atmcorr-S2/jupyer_notebooks[I 10:25:15.129 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 10:25:15.129 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/?token=...
[I 10:25:15.129 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 10:25:15.130 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 10:25:15.131 NotebookApp]

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=...
```

Also noticed that the error `No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.`

Comment: Did you use `-p 8888:8888` when running the image with `docker run`?

Comment: Yes, exactly as the instruction.

Comment: Try using your ip address:8888 instead of localhost:8888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I should use my IP address: `http://192.168.99.100:8888/?token=...`.

Reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/a4gvnm/localhost_refused_to_connect/?utm_content=full_comments&utm_medium=message&utm_source=reddit&utm_name=frontpage

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got any further with it, i'm struggeling somewhere in this process as well. But did you consider the following:

1) test if Docker is working:

```
docker run hello-world
```

2) If it is not: check virtualization and if you have hyper V installed. If it is working try to check if the created image is correctly displayed with this code in cmd:

```
docker images
```

It should display the image in correct name: *atmcorr-timeseries*.

if these are not the problems you probably have to give some more details? Where is everything installed, which versions do you have running etc?

Comment: No, I haven't. `docker images` give me "repository, tag, image ID, created, size", which shows 2 repositories `hello-world` and `samsammurphy/ee-python3-jupyter-atmcorr`. `gee-atmcorr-S2` is located in the `Docker Toolbox` folder. Any thoughts?

Comment: This suggest the hello world test works and the atmcorr-timeseries command as well, strangely enough the name (yours is _samsammurphy/ee-python3-jupyter-atmcorr_) is different than I was expecting? In the build command you specify the name which appears to be different with you perhaps try running the image:

so instead of `docker run -i -t -p 8888:8888 atmcorr-timeseries` try:
`docker run -i -t -p 8888:8888 samsammurphy/ee-python3-jupyter-atmcorr`

I'm also unaware about the effect of different python versions.

Comment: I couldn't find `atmcorr-timeseries`, where did you see it? Yes, `$ docker run -i -t -p 8888:8888 samsammurphy/ee-python3-jupyter-atmcorr:v1.0` was the one I used.

Comment: The [original](https://github.com/samsammurphy/ee-atmcorr-timeseries) instruction suggest using `docker run -i -t -p 8888:8888 atmcorr-timeseries`, but the run function depends on the name you supplied in the build function. 

Again without specifying the exact steps and code you went through, allowing to replicate your steps it will be dificult to find the problem.

Comment: Please find my edited question, hope it's clearer than before.